# Laravel y Ajax para obtener datos

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, laravel, rutas

Espero explicarme lo mejor posible para que me deis una ayudita.:S

Tengo el siguiente código de JavaScript:

```
 $.ajax({
url: "{{ route('comprobar') }}",
method: 'get',
dataType: 'json',
success: function(respuesta) {
  console.log("información");

},
error: function() {
  console.log("No se ha podido obtener la información");
}});
```

Y los siguientes códigos corresponden a la ruta de Laravel y su controlador:

```
Route::get('comprobar',[
'as'=>'comprobar',
'uses'=> 'CrearPersonajeController@comprobar']);


function comprobar()
{
    $idUsuario = \Auth::user()->id;
    $respuesta= DB::select("SELECT * FROM partidas WHERE idUsuario = " . $idUsuario );
    dd($respuesta);

    return Response::json(array());
}
```

El problema que me ocurre es que siempre entra en la parte de : No se ha podido obtener información y no se me ocurre cuál puede ser una solución ya que lo que quiero es extraer datos de la base de datos con Ajax para hacer un par de comprobaciones en un formulario con pasos(steps), añado también que me da un error por la consola del navegador : jquery.min.js:4 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/comprobar 500 (Internal Server Error) . Muchas gracias por su tiempo.

He podido mejorar el código de javascript/jquery para que me devuelva true o false en caso de que no encuentre lo que necesito pero mi problema ahora radica en que esa función no me devuelve nada a la variable que le asigno.

```js
 var nickPartida = document.getElementById('nickPartida').value;
 var devuelta = comprobarNickPartida(nickPartida);
 //aqui me duelve indefinido cuando en la función principal devuelve true
 console.log(devuelta);

function comprobarNickPartida(nickPartida)
{     
  var devolver = false;
   $(document).ready(function(){
      //Comprobación del nombre mediante Ajax
      $.ajax({
      url: "{{ route('comprobar') }}",
      method: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response) {
        //Comprobar que el nick existe en el array o si el tamaño 
        //del array es mas de uno para decirle al usuario que ya existe
       
        for (let index = 0; index < response.length; index++) 
        { 
          if(response[index]['nickPartida'] == nickPartida)
          {
            devolver = true;
          }
        }
        return devolver;
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log("No se ha podido obtener la información");
      }
    });
   })

   return devolver;
}
```

Comment: La petición ajax la estas haciendo desde un archivo `.js` o desde una plantilla `blade`?

Comment: Ya he resuelto la pregunta, la he respondido

Comment: Ok, solo por aclarar, si tu petición ajax se encuentra en un fichero externo a una plantilla `blade` de laravel, el helper `{{ route('comprobar') }}` no va a funcionar, talvez hay se encontraba tu problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno después de dos días de lleno metido con el código para hacerlo con Ajax, he optado por hacerlo vía el controlador de Laravel y pasarlo a la vista y comprobarlo desde ahí. Os dejó el código para que lo podáis ver mas claramente.

```
 function index(){
    $idUsuario = \Auth::user()->id;
    $response= DB::select("SELECT nickPartida FROM partidas WHERE idUsuario = " . $idUsuario );

    return view('crearpersonaje',compact('response'));
}
```

Desde ahí lo paso a la vista y trabajo con ella en la comprobación directamente :

```
<script> var arrayNombres = <?php echo(json_encode($response)); ?></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/propio.js')}}"></script>
<script>
 var inputNickPartida = document.getElementById('nickPartida');
 var existeNick = false;
 for (let index = 0; index < arrayNombres.length; index++) {
  if(arrayNombres[index]['nickPartida'] == inputNickPartida.value){
    console.log("existe");
    existeNick = true;
    document.getElementById('nickPartida').setAttribute('class',inputNickPartida.className + " invalid");
    }
  }
</script>
```

Gracias por la ayuda de todas formas y espero ayudar yo también en cualquier consulta que pueda atender.

Answer (score 0):

Los errores de ajax no los puedes ver en la consola del navegador, cuando ocurre un error del lado del servidor la única información que obtendras sera esa, 500 (Internal Server Error). Para ver el error real debes ir a la sección Network de las herramientas de desarrollador, mientras estés ahí, realiza la acción que envía el ajax y podrás ver el error real.

Comment: Buenas, gracias por ese consejo, he visto que la acción la hace correcta y no da tal error como he podido ver pero sigo sin poder entrar en la function que parte del success.